# Cannot create User

Tags: sql-server, keycloak, keycloak-services

Keycloak was working just fine, but suddenly the users can not create accounts and this warning was appears on the Keycloak logs

> Could not create user: org.keycloak.models.ModelException: jakarta.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Unexpected row count: -1; expected: 1; statement executed: insert into USER_ENTITY (CREATED_TIMESTAMP,EMAIL,EMAIL_CONSTRAINT,EMAIL_VERIFIED,ENABLED,FEDERATION_LINK,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,NOT_BEFORE,REALM_ID,SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_LINK,USERNAME,ID) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

We are using SQL Server 2019 for Keycloak, I just failover the database to run on the secondary node then Keycloak start to work.

- what does it mean (Unexpected row count: -1; expected: 1;)and why it happened?
- is it normal to send values as (?)?
- how to make sure it is not happening again?
- I restarted the keycloak cluster but it did not work.
- if its a transaction held the records, why it is happening?
- create the user by Application via API to DB.
- no trigger has been configured on the DB.

Comment: How did you try to add a new user?

Comment: *"is it normal to send values as (?)?"* Those `?` are parameter markers, and it's quite a common format in some languages.

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the table? Perhaps someone added a SELECT or something, -1 means there's a resultset or a record count row returned from jdbc

Comment: creating user by the application it sends the request via keycloak API to the database. , there is no trigger on the table, it was implemented as is .